# Visibility won't toggle in flutter?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-test

I've got a gridView where each grid has a FlatButton inside it. The button is supposed to trigger the visibility for another button I have outside the GridView. I've set the state in onPressed to change the bool showCard for everytime the GridView button is pressed. In my print statement, it's saying that it's working, producing true and false each time the button is pressed, but it's not changing the visibility of the other button called 'CheckoutCard()'. Can anyone help me?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:bee/Cards/Items%20Card.dart';
import 'package:bee/Constants/Constants.dart';
import 'package:bee/MerchantCategories/My Categories.dart';
import 'package:bee/MenuButtons/Color Changer.dart';
import 'package:bee/Cards/Checkout Card.dart';
import 'package:bee/main.dart';
import 'Basket Menu.dart';

class MyMenu extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyMenuState createState() => _MyMenuState();

}

class _MyMenuState extends State<MyMenu> {

//  bool showCard = _MyButtonState().showCard;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(

        brightness: Brightness.light,

        leading: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () { Navigator.of(context).pop();},
        ),

        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          child: Image(image: AssetImage('images/Merchants/My_Image.png'),),
        ),
        elevation: 1.0,
        centerTitle: true,

        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
            child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket, color: Colors.blue[800],),
            onPressed: (){ Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){return BasketMenu();})); }
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),





      body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flex(
              direction: Axis.vertical,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
                        MyCategories(categoryText: Text('Restaurants', style: categoryTextStyle),),
                        MyCategories(categoryText: Text('Bars', style: categoryTextStyle),),
                        MyCategories(categoryText: Text('Games', style: categoryTextStyle),),

                      ],
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              Expanded(
                  flex: 10,
                  child: Container(

                    child: GridView.count(

                      crossAxisCount: 2,

                      children: <Widget>[


                        ItemsCard(
                          categoryName: Text('Fast Food', style: secondCategoryTextStyle,),
                          itemText: FastFoodText,
                          priceText: Text('£21.67', style: priceTextStyle,),
                          gridOutline: MyButton(
                            tile: GridTile(
                              child: FastFoodImage,
                          ),
                          ),
                        ),


                        ItemsCard(
                          itemText: SnubbText,
                          priceText: Text('£44.95', style: priceTextStyle,),
                          gridOutline: MyButton(
                            tile: GridTile(
                                child: SnubbImage,
                              ),
                          ),
                        ),


                        ItemsCard(
                          itemText: FreshText,
                          priceText: Text('£41.23', style: priceTextStyle,),
                          gridOutline: MyButton(
                            tile: GridTile(
                                child: FreshImage,
                              ),
                          ),
                        ),


                        Container(),


                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            Visibility(visible: _MyButtonState().showCard ? _MyButtonState().showCard : !_MyButtonState().showCard, child: CheckoutCard()),

          ],
      ),

    );

  }
}


class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return _MyButtonState();
  }

  MyButton({this.tile});
  final GridTile tile;

  bool isVisible = false;
  int itemNumber = 0;

  bool showCheckoutCard(){
    return isVisible = !isVisible;
  }

  int itemCounter(){
    return itemNumber++;
  }

}


class _MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {

  bool changeColor = false;

  static var myNewButtonClass = MyButton();

  bool showCard = myNewButtonClass.isVisible;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      shape: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: changeColor ? Colors.blue[800] : Colors.transparent, width: 3.0)),
      child: widget.tile,
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          changeColor = !changeColor;
          myNewButtonClass.itemCounter();
          print(myNewButtonClass.itemCounter());
          setState(() {
            showCard = !showCard;
            print(showCard);
          });
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you make your problem and code more concise? You want to be able to click one button and have that show another button, and so on?

Comment: That's right, yeah. I just can't toggle the visibility widget through the bool showCard, which is set in MyButton()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `setState` method inside your `Button`. I don't think it will change the state of your `MyMenu` widget. I would suggest you to change your `Button` as following:

```
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final GridTile tile;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  const MyButton({Key key, this.color, this.tile, this.onPressed})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      shape: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: color)),
      child: tile,
      onPressed: onPressed,
    );
  }
}
```

After that, you need to declare two variable in your `MyMenu` widget as follows:

```
class _MyMenuState extends State<MyMenu> {
  bool changeColor = false;
  bool showCard = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    yourBuildMethod()
```

In your `MyMenu` widget you can call button like this:

```
MyButton(
  tile: GridTile(child: SnubbImage),
  color: changeColor
    ? Colors.blue[800]
    : Colors.transparent,
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      changeColor = !changeColor;
      showCard = !showCard;
    });
  },
),
```

And now check your `Visibility` like this:

```
Visibility(
  visible: showCard,
  child: CheckoutCard(),
)
```

Now your variables are in your `MyMenu` widget and you are calling `setState` function in `MyMenu` widget. So it will be able to update the state of your widget. I hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: You bloody genius

Answer (score 1):

To trigger a rebuild of your view based when changing the value of a variable you need to use `setState`.
Where you are are changing the value of the `isVisible` variable, you need to surround it with a `setState`:

```
setState(() {
  isVisible = !isVisible;
});
```

Comment: Already tried it, hasn't seemed to have had an effect. Thanks for trying to help, appreciate the effort

Comment: @JamesPiner Where are you using the `showCheckoutCard()` method? it's not on your code.

Comment: I actually don't need to use it - I used it before to try and make the visibility work, but it also had no effect. I just never called the method and instead setState((){ showCard = !showCard });